# Pursuing a PhD in quantum computing

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I'm looking for a PhD in Quantun Computing, but I don't know how or where can I achieve that. Currently I'm in Chile finishing my Bs. degree in physics. I also want to know if there is any recommendation/data about south american being accepted at universities abroad.

I asked in my university if they can help me, but thet say that they are not capable of helping me in this situation. My grades are very good, translating into a gpa of >=3.7

I really want to achieve this, but I really don't know how to start this path.

Comment: If you're considering Europe as destination, then be aware that a master's degree is often required for a PhD (outside UK). Getting into a master's program is not so hard (but you should look for stipends), and it will certainly make it easier to get a PhD position afterwards (luckily there is also plenty of funding in QC right now).

Comment: And I agree with Anja below, there are a lot of South and Latin Americans in QC. Many of them do their PhD (and possibly master before) abroad. https://quantiki.org/ is a good source for PhD openings, and they also have a list of quantum groups worldwide. The latter is probably a bit outdated by now.

Comment: To add to Markus Heinrich's comment - a master's degree is definitely required for getting a PhD in the UK in quantum computing (at least, if your undergrad degree was 3/4 years only). If you can (especially if you can get your current university to pay for it), it might be worth it to attend a conference related to the specific subfield you are interested in, to do some networking. For example, QPL is being held in Buenos Aires this year.

Answer (score 3):

A friend of mine was in a similar situation, trying to navigate the complex world of PhDs in Quantum Computing. Here’s what he did and what I learned from his experience:

1. Research Programs and Universities
   First, he spent a significant amount of time researching various PhD programs in Quantum Computing. He looked into universities not just in the US and Europe, but also in Asia and Australia, since these regions also have strong research programs in physics and quantum computing. Websites like [topuniversities.com](https://topuniversities.com) and specific university websites were invaluable for this.
2. Networking
   Networking played a crucial role. He reached out to professors whose research interests aligned with his, via email. He introduced himself, outlined his academic background, and expressed his interest in their research. Some professors were kind enough to offer advice and information about their programs. He also got in touch with current PhD students in some of these programs, who provided insights into the application process and the program itself.
3. Preparing for GRE and TOEFL/IELTS
   Since he was applying to universities abroad, he had to prepare for the GRE and TOEFL exams. These scores were required for most of the applications. He dedicated several months to study for these exams, using online resources and practice tests to improve his scores.
4. Application Documents
   He spent a lot of time crafting his Statement of Purpose (SOP) and updating his CV. The SOP was particularly important, as it allowed him to narrate his academic journey, research interests, and why he was a good fit for the programs he was applying to. He also sought feedback from his mentors and peers to refine his SOP and CV.
5. Scholarships and Funding
   He looked for scholarship opportunities and funding options since PhD programs abroad can be expensive. Many universities offer scholarships, research assistantships, and teaching assistantships to international PhD students.

From what my friend found, universities are generally looking for talented and passionate students, regardless of their nationality. Having a strong academic record (like a GPA of >=3.7), a clear research proposal, and good communication skills can significantly enhance your application. He also noticed a good representation of students from South America in some programs, which is encouraging.